# Bad sexp error on custom diary function

Tags: debugging, diary

I've created a diary function to allow me to record cyclic events. 
So something like `(diary-limited-cyclic-weekday 8 '(0 3 6) 01 01 2018)` will create an event for every Sunday, Wednesday, and Saturday since the start date. So in the example: the 3, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 17, and 20th of January 2018 should be marked with an event.

I put this function in an org file as:

`* Blooop
<%%(diary-limited-cyclic-weekday 8 '(0 3 6) 01 01 2018)> 09:00-10:00`

When I run it I get

`Bad sexp at line 9 in /home/luis/Documents/org/agenda/schedule.org: (let ((entry ) (date (quote (1 1 2018)))) (diary-limited-cyclic-weekday 8 (quote (0 3 6)) 1 1 2018))`

I get subsequent errors just like this except with the day in `(quote (1 1 2018))` incremented by 1.
For example:

```
Bad sexp at line 9 ... (quote 1 2 2018)...
Bad sexp at line 9 ... (quote 1 3 2018)...
...
```

At first this made me think that perhaps my function was too slow and because of this taking too long to return a value for a single date.

I wrote this function trying to emulate the `diary-limited-cyclic` function I found online.

What could be the problem with my function? Note that even when I remove the potentially complicated `(> recurrences ...)` sexp at the end, and expect it to just return every Sun, Wed, Sat afterwards, I get the same error.

```
(defun diary-limited-cyclic-weekday (recurrences weekdays m d y)
  "For use in emacs diary. Cyclic item with a limited number of occurences.
WEEKDAYS is a list of the days of the week (0-6) in which event will repeat starting on
  YYYY-MM-DD, for a total of RECURRENCES occasions."
  (let* ((today-day (calendar-day-of-week date))
         (today (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian date))
         (start (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (list m d y)))
         (start-day (calendar-day-of-week start))
         (day-range (- today start)))

    (and (not (cl-minusp day-range)) ; not less than start day
         (cl-member today-day weekdays) ; is one of the desired weekdays
         ;; number of target weekdays in full weeks
         ;; + number of target weekdays in remainder days
         (> recurrences (+ (* (cl-list-length weekdays) (cl-mod day-range 7)) 
                           (cl-loop
                            for day from start-day to (+ start-day (cl-rem day-range 7))
                            count (cl-member day weekdays)))))))


(defun diary-limited-cyclic (recurrences interval m d y)                    
  "For use in emacs diary. Cyclic item with limited number of recurrences.    
Occurs every INTERVAL days, starting on YYYY-MM-DD, for a total of          
RECURRENCES occasions."                                                     
  (let ((startdate (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (list m d y)))           
        (today (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian date)))                            
    (and (not (cl-minusp (- today startdate)))                                  
         (zerop (% (- today startdate) interval))                                    
         (< (floor (- today startdate) interval) recurrences))))
```

Comment: I see that the way you use it, `diary-sexp-entry` is actually not used, instead `org-diary-sexp-entry` is used, which does more or less the same thing, except it doesn't show the actual error !!  Please `M-: (setq calendar-debug-sexp t) RET` and then reproduce the error (you should then get a full backtrace).

Comment: This really helped! Now that I could see the error I debugged the method and got it working. I will post the working method below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stefan's advice to add set the variable `calendar-debug-sexp` to `t`. Allowed me to see the full stacktrace when debugging `diary-limited-cyclic-weekday`.

The problems were fairly simple. `calendar-day-of-the-week` expected a list of the form `(m d y)` but I was giving `date` variable. I'm actually unsure as to why `date` works as a parameter for `calendar-absolute-from-gregorian` but not `calendar-day-of-the-week` as according to their documentation they both need a list fo the form `(m d y)` but I suspect the answer to this lies in the documentation Stefan referenced in his answer above.

Another change I made was change `cl-mod` to `floor` when I realized `cl-mod` and `cl-rem` both get the remainder and that to get the number of full weeks I needed the floor. Finally, I changed the `(> recurrences...)` to   `(>= recurrences...)` to make sure there are a `recurrences` number of days chosen in the calendar instead of `recurrences - 1` days.

```
(defun diary-limited-cyclic-weekday (recurrences weekdays m d y)
  "For use in emacs diary. Cyclic item with a limited number of occurences.
WEEKDAYS represents the days of the week in which event will repeat starting on YYYY-MM-DD, for a total of RECURRENCES occasions."
  (let* ((today-day (calendar-day-of-week date))
     (today (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian date))
     (start (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (list m d y)))
     (start-day (calendar-day-of-week (list m d y)))
     (day-range (- today start)))

(and (not (cl-minusp day-range))
     (cl-member today-day weekdays)
     (>= recurrences (+ (* (cl-list-length weekdays) (floor day-range 7)) 
                        (cl-loop
                         for day from start-day to (+ start-day (cl-rem day-range 7))
                         count (cl-member day weekdays)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the probem, but `(diary-limited-cyclic-weekday 8 '(0 3 6) 01 01 2018))` has an extra finbal parenthesis.  Maybe that's just it (tho it's unlikely); if not, please provide the actual error message (the part after "Bad diary sexp at line NN in FOO:").

As for the `date` variable, it is provided by dynamic scoping.  Not sure exactly where this is documented (I haven't checked the manual), but technically, the var is provided from `diary-sexp-entry`.  It's at least mentioned in the docstring of `diary-list-entries`:

> ... Note that hook functions should *not* use `date`, but `original-date`.
>   (Sexp diary entries may use `date` - see `diary-list-sexp-entries`.) ...

as well as the docstring of `diary-list-sexp-entries`:

> ... The form of a sexp diary entry is
>
> ```
>              %%(SEXP) ENTRY
> ```
>
> Both `entry` and `date` are available when the SEXP is evaluated. ...

Comment: I've added more information about the error and removed the extra parentheses as that was just a typo when writing the question.

Comment: I also removed the second question as to how diary works because I realized it was problematic choosing the accepted answer when I have 2 different questions.